# Where is the OS X Remote Desktop Client

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

An update to the remote desktop client was recently applied to my MacBook via the software updater.  I can't find this application anywhere.  What is this application called and where is it located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take advantage of the functionality you've just seen updated, you probably need "[Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/specs.html)", which seems to be an enterprise remote management tool like Microsoft's [Systems Management Server](http://www.microsoft.com/smserver/default.mspx), but for OSX.

The update you're referring to probably updated unseen client-side support built into OS X.  For desktops that aren't being managed by [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/specs.html), I would guess the update is innocuous.

**UPDATE**: For what it's worth, I just ran Software Update on my own MacBook and saw the update you're referring to.  Here's the [link to Apple Support's article describing the update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3670).  In fact, it mentions:

> [...] Apple Remote Desktop Client 3.3.1
>   **updates the software that facilitates
>   Remote Management** (enabled in Sharing
>   preferences, in System Preferences). [...]
>   [*emphasis mine*]

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps you’re referring to the Screen Sharing app. It’s in Macintosh HD > System > Library > CoreServices.

P.S. You don’t need to launch this app directly to connect to another computer via VNC. You can just go to Finder > Go > Connect to Server… (or press ⌘K) and enter vnc:// and the address of the remote computer. This app is also used by the Back To My Mac screen-sharing feature.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Do either "Remote Management" or "Screen Sharing" need to be enabled? to do this?

Answer (score 6):

On Yosemite, you'll want to use the `Screen Sharing` application.  You'll find it here:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Screen Sharing.app`

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the Apple Remote Desktop app, assuming it was installed and purchased, info can be found [here](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/).

If you're talking about the Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection, it's [here](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx).

In either event, if they're installed, they'll be in your Applications folder.

Answer (score 1):

The update in specific updated the programs found at `/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/` - specifically ARDAgent.app

ARDAgent goes hand in hand with [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/specs.html) which is used to help manage multiple Macs either through controlling (ala VNC), copying files, installing packages, restarting, etc. For most people it's a non-issue. For businesses or other places that use Apple Remote Desktop the new version brings some very nice bug fixes. (I'll never log myself out again trying to log off a remote computer again!)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Cross-post [from AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93791/does-screen-sharing-work-when-not-on-the-same-local-network/229255#229255) for Googlers</sup>

If you are trying to access one of your own computers that uses **your** same Apple ID, the best method is to use [Back to My Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18696?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).

You have to make sure you enable "Back to My Mac" in the iCloud Preference Pane on **both** computers:

[image]

Under the Sharing Preferences pane disable Remote Management if it is enabled, and then enable Screen Sharing.

[image]

Wait a moment and your computer should show up in Finder under the Shared section.

[image]

If you don't see a "Shared" section or the computer doesn't appear there, click on Finder and then open Finder's preferences (⌘+,) and make sure that everything in the Shared section is selected:

[image]