# Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) - included in snow leopard 10.6.6?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, remote-desktop

Is the Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) included in snow leopard 10.6.6 ?

I have done a software update and i get the Remote Desktop Update 3.4. But i cant find the Apple Remote Desktop Client on my Mac (How do i launch it) ?

Comment: The confusion arises from the fact that what is technically server software included on every OS X installation is listed as "Apple Remote Desktop Client" in software updates and the like. It's really more "Apple Remote Desktop software _for_ Clients," whereas the actual client software is called the ARD Admin Console.

Answer (score 2):

The client is included as part of the OS. The admin software is a separate purchase. You can configure the client in System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Management.

Additionally if you want to connect to a remote machine Screen Sharing is available on all OS X client machines. As long as the machine you want to connect to has Screen Sharing or Remote Management turned on in the Sharing System Pref pane, you can share the screen and control the desktop. You can access this through the Finder on the sidebar under the Shared browser. This will show you all the machines on your local network that have sharing on, or any machines you have configured with Back to My Mac. There is a nice free utility called ScreenSharingMenulet that sits in your menu bar and gives quick access to machines with screen sharing on.

Comment: The *server* (or at least *a server*) is configured in that Sharing preference pane.

Comment: Correct it is the server, but running on the client. The configuration here defines access to the client machine from an admin machine. There is also a command line option for configuration and management called kicskstart. /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart

Comment: You can edit your answer to incorporate new information.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the Apple Remote Desktop Client in the mac world is a 'server' - i thinked that i can connect to other macs using this client.

Comment: The terminology is wrong here. Remote Desktop Client is the client, and it's used to control another Mac. What you configure in System Preferences is the server, i.e. when you want to control *this* Mac remotely. I'm not sure the configuration Wilersh mentions is for ARD, maybe it's just VNC/Screen Sharing.

Comment: I've flagged your question for moderator attention, to get your accounts merged and make you the owner of the question again. When that's done, then please delete this non-answer and, if applicable, either repost as a comment, or edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: ok sorry for trouble

Comment: (I'm not sure the flagging came through; you could try again: just click the flag link on the question, or this answer, en explain to a moderator.)

Comment: unfortunately i am only a guest and cant flag ...

Comment: @Arjan We are awaiting feedback from the devs with regards to merging accounts. Moderators can't merge accounts unless both actually exist on the site.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are also looking for the actual application that used to be located in Application/Utilities folder, called Screen Sharing. It is now hidden away at /System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing. This is the actual app that is called by the finder wihen using either the sidebar or Connect to... to remotely screen share.

Answer (score 2):

First enable Remote Desktop in the system Sharing prefs on the mac you want to connect to.  Then in Finder on the mac you want to connect from, select `Go -> Connect to Server` and enter `vnc://<machine name or ip>`.

[Where is the OS X Remote Desktop Client](https://superuser.com/questions/27387/where-is-the-os-x-remote-desktop-client?rq=1)